# issue with float increment in Android

Tags: java, android, floating-point, increment, floating-accuracy

I am trying to increment value of float by 0.1 every time. But i am getting very strange result some time.

```
float kmVal = 0.0f;    
EditText kms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.km);
kmVal = Float.valueOf(kms.getText().toString());
```

On Click of button I am incrementing the value.

```
kmVal += 0.1;
kms.setText(String.valueOf(kmVal));
```

**LOG :-**

```
06-24 13:16:21.644: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.1
06-24 13:16:21.644: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.1
06-24 13:16:21.886: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-24 13:16:22.145: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.2
06-24 13:16:22.145: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.2
06-24 13:16:22.384: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.3
06-24 13:16:22.384: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.3
06-24 13:16:22.484: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.4
06-24 13:16:22.484: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.4
06-24 13:16:22.684: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.5
06-24 13:16:22.684: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.5
06-24 13:16:22.868: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.6
06-24 13:16:22.874: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.6
06-24 13:16:23.056: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.70000005
06-24 13:16:23.064: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.70000005
06-24 13:16:23.884: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.8000001
06-24 13:16:23.884: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.8000001
06-24 13:16:23.964: D/dalvikvm(353): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 44% free 3532K/6279K, external 716K/1038K, paused 106ms
06-24 13:16:24.536: I/System.out(958): Value ==0.9000001
06-24 13:16:24.536: I/System.out(958): String Value ==0.9000001
```

As you can see from the log that the value upto 0.6 are ok but after that its adding extra digits that i don't want. I don't know why i am getting such result. If anyone has any idea please kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: This is not specific to Android, or even Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because how the floating type numbers are represented. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3):

> The finite nonzero values of any floating-point value set can all be expressed in the form s · m · 2(e - N + 1), where s is +1 or -1, m is a positive integer less than 2N, and e is an integer between Emin = -(2K-1-2) and Emax = 2K-1-1, inclusive, and where N and K are parameters that depend on the value set.

Hence, float values cannot accurately represent base 10 real numbers. While you might get the initial `0.1` , what actually happens is you are getting `0.0999999999999999996` which is turned into `0.1`. But as you keep on doing operations on it, it keeps losing precision.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936219/help-with-float-numbers-in-java) for more.

For precision use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal("0.1");
test = test.add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need exact representation of floating-point values, then indeed you can't use simple floating point types like `double` or `float` in any language. In Java, you could use `BigDecimal`. But, I'd first figure out whether you really need this exact floating-point or not.

Comment: Can you please kindly help me in this. How can i get exact floating point.

Comment: Read the javadoc for `java.math.BigDecimal` first please. Start with `BigDecimal kmVal = new BigDecimal(kms.getText().toString());`