# strange number of repetitions in for loop

Tags: java, loops, numbers, precision

I wrote this little program to calculate pi.

While playing with the code and trying to find the most exact result, I found a point where my computer couldn't calalculate a result. It could do **33554430** repetitions within seconds, but if i increased the for loop to **33554431** it didn't output anything.

So is **33554430** a special number?

```
public class CalculatePi{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        float pi=0;
        int sign=1;
        for(float i=1; i <= 33554430; i+=2){
            pi += (sign*(1.0/i));
            sign*= -1;
        }
        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println(pi);
     }

}
```

Comment: ***for(float i=1;*** charming!!!

Comment: it takes about two seconts to calculate 33554430, but it took minutes with 33554431 until I stopped it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting and endless loop, because during the comparison `i <= 33554431`, the `int` value `33554431` is [promoted to a `float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) value which is "too precise" for float and will actually equal to `33554432`.
Then, when you try to increase the value by `+2`, the `float` just isn't precise enough to increment from the value `33554432`. To illustrate my point:

```
float f = 33554432;
System.out.println(f); //33554432
f += 2;
System.out.println(f); //33554432
```

So the value `f` doesn't increase due to its precision limitation. If you'd increase it by, say `11`, you'd get `33554444` (and not `33554443`) as that is the closest number expressible with that precision.

> So is **33554430** a special number?

Sort of, not 33554430 but rather 33554432. First "special number" for float is `16777217`, which is the first positive integer that cannot be represented as a `float` (equals `16777216` as float). So, if you'd increment your `i` variable by `1`, this is the number you'd get stuck on. Now, since you are incrementing by `2`, the number you get stuck on is `16777216 * 2 = 33554432`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CalculatePi{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        float pi=0;
        int sign=1;
        for(float i=1; i <= 33554431; i+=2){
            pi += (sign*(1.0/i));
            sign*= -1;
        if( i > 33554410) System.out.println(i);
        }
        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println(pi);

        System.out.println((float)33554431);
        System.out.println((float)33554432);
        System.out.println((float)33554434);
     }

}
```

You compare float with int in for loop. When you convert `33554431` (it's int value) to float you get `3.3554432E7`.

It's about accuracy, precision. When you run:

```
System.out.println((float)33554431);  // -> 3.3554432E7
System.out.println((float)33554432);  // -> 3.3554432E7
System.out.println((float)33554434);  // -> 3.3554432E7
```

All 3 prints `3.3554432E7`, it means that when you increase float value of 33554432 by 2, you get `3.3554432E7`, exactly this same value, and your loop runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

This version works for both. It's the float loop variable causing problems:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        float pi=0;
        int sign=1;
        for(int i=1; i <= 33554430; i+=2){
            pi += (sign*(1.0/(float)i));
            sign*= -1;
        }
        pi *= 4;
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
```

Probably this is due this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175922/issue-with-float-increment-in-android):

> The finite nonzero values of any floating-point value set can all be
>   expressed in the form s · m · 2(e - N + 1), where s is +1 or -1, m is
>   a positive integer less than 2N, and e is an integer between Emin =
>   -(2K-1-2) and Emax = 2K-1-1, inclusive, and where N and K are parameters that depend on the value set.

Comment: so the number is too big for float?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop increments by 2 each time.

2 * 33554430 = 67108860

2 ^ 26 = 67108864

Maybe Java stores floating point numbers in a 32bit system by using 26bits for the mantissa and 6 bits for the exponent?