# Why Precision in Floating number sums getting altered? How this works?

Tags: java, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results-in-java)
>   [Float numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936219/float-numbers-in-java)

Please see Code Below.

```
public class TestSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float a = 4.8f;//try with 4.7f
    float b = 4.5f;//try with 4.6f
    double sum = a + b;
    System.out.println(sum);
 }
}

(4.8f+4.5f) sum=9.300000190734863
```

But when, i tried `(4.7f+4.6f)` it gives `sum = 9.299999237060547`
Again,

```
(1.8f+1.5f) sum=3.299999952316284.
(1.7f+1.6f) sum=3.3000001907348633.
```

But,

```
(2.8f+2.5f) sum=5.300000190734863.
(2.7f+2.6f) sum=5.300000190734863.
```

I want to Understand, how this works. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And Google didn't answer ? Please have a look at the many links on the right of this page.

Comment: @Alex See IEEE 754 this has been asked too many times.

Comment: And I can't imagine the answer wasn't in one of the many suggestions you had when typing the title of this question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your answer was really Helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to understand how this works.

See the info. & links (listed below) on the [floating point tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info).

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

> What's best solution for this then...?

[`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), or more commonly, formatting the output using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is common to all programming languages, and it is due to the finite precision of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone For Helping me here.

But i asked this question, to understand why doesn't this happens in Python,Ruby or JavaScript, but in Java.

I think one Possible solution for precision is to go with double

```
   public class TestSum {
   public static void main(String[] args){
   double a = 4.8d;
   double b = 4.5d;
   double sum = a + b;
   System.out.println(sum);
   }
   }
```

Comment: *"I think one Possible solution for precision is to go with double"*  No.  Try more combinations.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah you are right. It Doesn't work either. What's best solution for this then...?

Comment: [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), or more commonly formatting the output using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: This makes the question more precise. It DOES happen in Python,Ruby or JavaScript :) It does happen in all programming languages, if you are using floating-point math. And it happens at different levels; using single-precision floats makes the problem apparent in more cases, while using double-precision floats may hide it in many cases. And I suspect that most of the dynamic languages you mentioned use by default double-precision floating point numbers

Comment: As @AndrewThompson pointed out, going from floating point numbers to fixed point-precise representations will solve the precision problem, at the expense of performance of course (I would not use it in games, for example)